# So what's with the [tag:time] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

Noticed this a couple of days ago - we have a [time](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time) tag with no description that keeps getting used (I've removed it from a couple of questions this week).  Should we keep it? Define it? Get rid of it?

(Yes, I'm asking us to define time. Wax philosophically about that, y'all)

Comment: [This question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/10419/444) is really about time zones, and I have re-tagged it as such, leaving now only one question with the 'time' tag.

Comment: And the [only other question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/26083/444) with the 'time' tag really isn't about time, either... it's about travel times.  I know we have other questions about that... I'm not sure if/how they're tagged.

Comment: We already have a tag timezone that is better suited in this case.

Answer (score 7):

I removed the tag from questions that didn't really need it, and only two remained that kind of need it -- when the concept of time keeping itself is discussed, not e.g. "how much time to spend in Zanzibar". I think that should be the intended tag use, if we decide to keep it at all. Suggestions for tag synonyms welcome.

**Update**: As @Flimsy points out, only one question remained with the tag, and it didn't really help in explaining the question, so I removed it as well. Thus, the tag has no current questions associated to it currently, though if questions on time-keeping do arise in the future, it would be the appropriate tag to add. Meanwhile, it will be removed automatically at some point in the future if no questions use it.

We could possibly ban it, but I don't see a strong case for this as it stands.

Comment: And suggestions for a tag description, perhaps...last I checked it didn't have one.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that we need the time tag. For the questions that @mindcorrosive pointed out, we already have a [planning](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planning). For the question that Flimzy mentioned, we have [timezones](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/timezones) that is better suited for this case.